# INSTRUMENT_DECLINED during PayPal sandbox payment

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am testing a web app with a *PayPal* express checkout button

I click on *Pay now*, I log-in with one of my **sandbox** accounts and pay with Paypal fundings, but payment doesn't end well and I receive a 400 error: `{"ack":"contingency","contingency":"INSTRUMENT_DECLINED","meta":...`

my code is

```js
 paypal.button.render({
    env: 'sandbox',
    client: {
        sandbox:    'AAAAAAAAAAA',
        production: '<????>'
    },

    locale: 'en_US',                
    commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button
    style: {
        size:'medium',
        color: 'silver',
        label: 'pay',
    },
    payment: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.create({
            payment: {
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: { total: ctrl.amount, currency: 'EUR' }
                    }
                    ]
            },
            experience: {
                input_fields: {
                    no_shipping: 1
                }
            },
        });
    },

    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.execute().then(function(payment) {
            alert("Payment completed!");
            paymentCompleted();

        });
    },

    onCancel: function(data, actions) {
        alert("Payment doesn't end well :-(");
        location.href=location.href;
    }


}, '#paypal-button');
```

I noticed the same behaviour in [interactive demo](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client), I can login, pay, but the payment is not accepted due to INSTRUMENT_DECLINED.

Any idea about where can be the problem?
I tried to create different sandbox accounts, but nothing changes.

Comment: Experiencing the same error in a setup that has always worked fine. Probably a bug in the sandbox that will hopefully be fixed soon.

Comment: @cioddi thank you for your feedback. I wrote to PayPal assistance.

Comment: It seems to be solved now